# Badge Suggestion: "The People's Choice"

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I've noticed a lot of questions get a green tick early on, only to get a "better" answer after the fact, which gains far more up votes, yet the OP never returns to his post, or chooses to not update their chosen answer (and fair play, its their choice).

I do, however, think this should probably get a badge, possibly with levels based on just how far your answer outstrips the accepted answer in votes.

Example:

- Question: "How do I do x?"
- Answer 1 gets the job done, gets green tick and 5 up votes.
- Answer 2 then turns up, answers in a way that's far more use to future readers, the community upvotes this in buckets, giving it 20 up votes. It never gets the green tick, but does get a badge for gaining 4x the amount (and more than a minimum of 10 votes more).

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Populist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/37/populist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Populist badge is for those who score much higher than the accepted answer.

[image: Populist]

While it'd be nice to have a badge for those who actually change their accepted answer when a better one comes along, I'm not sure how you'd keep that from being gamed.  Maybe if you set an upvote ratio, like the populist badge and then the accept status was changed.